# If I forget to pull from Github and just work on it

Tags: git, github, push, pull-request

I'm wondering that is there any good way if I forget to `git pull` before I `git push` to GitHub.

Until now, I just `git clone` the repository to another location and overwrite the pulled files with new files that I worked on.

Comment: You can commit your work locally and do git pull after

Comment: You can pull the branch and merge the things together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#:%7E:text=DESCRIPTION,to%20match%20the%20HEAD%20commit.) your changes and [pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) or [commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) and then do a [pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) and [merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge). Stash doesn't stage your changes whereas commit does.

**With stash-**

```
git stash
git pull
git stash apply -- *(Can raise merge conflicts)*
git add .
git commit -m "{Your message}"
git push
```

**With commit-**

```
git add .
git commit -m "{Your message}"
git pull -- *(Can raise merge conflicts)*
git push
```

If merge results into conflicts, you'll need to resolve them. [Here's](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/en/command-line/advanced-topics/merge-conflicts/) a link that can help.

Comment: I didn't realize about git stash! Thanks for your answer, it gives me big help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could pull directly from remote

```
git pull origin your-current-branch-name
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "forget to pull before pushing". You cannot push until you pull! So forgetting is impossible; the remote repo won't let you forget.

So when you are ready to push, simply make one last commit (if you haven't already), then pull, then push.